# regex exec method doesnt work

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

```
var rgx = /<td.+ headers=["']d8.+ ["']>(.+)<\/td>/i,
    str = "<tr><td class='' headers='d8073e47 d8073e50 '>.cpp</td><td class='' headers='d8073e47 d8073e50 '>text/x-c</td></tr>",
    matches = [];
if(rgx.exec(str)&&rgx.exec(str)[1]) {
    console.log(rgx.exec(str)[1]);
    matches.push(rgx.exec(str)[1])
}
console.log(matches);
```

I have this code and it returns the last entity always. When I try to set global flag it gives error but this regex is supposed to match `.cpp` and `text/x-c`.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you're calling `exec`, you're iterating one step and going to the next match. You're doing it way too much.

You must also make the matching group not greedy. You should always be very careful when you write things like `.*` or `.+` as they can match more than what you want.

I fixed your code like this:

```
var rgx = /<td[^\>]+ headers=["']d8[^\>]+ ["']>(.+?)<\/td>/ig,
    str = "<tr><td class='' headers='d8073e47 d8073e50 '>.cpp</td><td class='' headers='d8073e47 d8073e50 '>text/x-c</td></tr>",
    matches = [],
    res;
while (res = rgx.exec(str)) {
   matches.push(res[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/yuwolatavo/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: when i try while loop with global flag it enters into infinite loop

Comment: Click the "Demonstration" link then the "Run with JS" button.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, you added a log of `rgx.exec(str)` ! log `res` instead. Every time you call `rgx.exec` you change the state of `rgx`

Comment: how it changes i dont modify anything inside rgx

Comment: Just doing `rgx.exec(str)` is modifying it. A global regex is stateful. Remove your `console.log(rgx.exec(str))` line.

Comment: @teresko imnot going to tell what u should start doing at this point guess it

Comment: @nikoss In your last screenshot, you don't even have the g flag. Of course it's an infinite loop. Either take my code as it is or try to understand it.